# Copying values from range in Excel to bookmark in Word

Tags: excel, vba

The following code copies a single value into a bookmark in Word.  I need it to copy a range of values like "A6:G20".

```vb
Sub test()
Dim objWord As Object
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Workbooks("Portfolio1").Sheets("Print")
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

objWord.Visible = True
objWord.Documents.Open "D:Q.docx" ' change as required

With objWord.ActiveDocument
 .Bookmarks("monthtable").Range.Text = ws.Range("C6").Value ' here I need range of values to be selected instead of a single cell
End With
Set objWord = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If suitable, you could copy and paste the range:

```
Range("A6:G20").Copy
.Bookmarks("monthtable").Range.PasteExcelTable False, False, False
```

There are a number of other Paste methods if you don't wish to paste as an Excel table. Use Word's VB Editor to discover these, or the Word Macro Recorder.

Answer (score 0):

This is of course the important part:

```
With objWord.ActiveDocument    
.Bookmarks("monthtable").Range.Text = ws.Range("C6").Value ' here i need range of values to be selected instead of a single cell
End With
```

Here you need to cycle through the ws.Range("..."), and for each cell in that range, *concatenate* that value onto the .Bookmarks.Range.Text value (Rather than setting it equal, which would overwrite).  It's probably a good idea to first concatenate this into a string variable and then set the bookmark to that string variable's value, since that would avoid some potential interop issues.